# Pythagorean triplets of the form $a^2+(a+1)^2=c^2$ and the space between them

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

I was searching for pythagorean triples where $b=a+1$, and I found using a python program I made the first 10 integer solutions:

1. $0^2+1^2=1^2$
2. $3^2+4^2=5^2$
3. $20^2+21^2=29^2$
4. $119^2+120^2=169^2$
5. $696^2+697^2=985^2$
6. $4059^2+4060^2=5741^2$
7. $23660^2+23661^2=33461^2$
8. $137903^2+137904^2=195025^2$
9. $803760^2+803761^2=1136689^2$
10. $4684659^2+4684660^2=6625109^2$

Now what's so interesting? I discovered that any $c$, divided by the previous (for example $5/1$ or $29/5$) limits to $5.828427...=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2-1}\right)^2=\sqrt8+3$. My question: why?

Comment: This is quite a nice observation! The explanation is closely related to the solutions of the Pell Equation. I'll let someone else write up the details, but the essential ingredients can be found in the comments of this OEIS entry: http://oeis.org/A001652

Comment: The difference between (n+1)^2 and n^2.  Is 2n+1 so these triplets are found by taking odd squares and setting that as the difference between squares. So the trips are (2m+1)^2,2m^2+ 2m, and c=2m^2+2m+1. So limit is m+2+1/2m over m-1.

Comment: We have $a^2+(a+1)^2=c^2$ if and only if $4a^2+4a+2=2c^2$ if and only if $(2a+1)^2-2c^2=-1$.  There is a nice formula for the solutions of the Pellian $x^2-2y^2=-1$, they are  obtained in a simple way from the odd powers of $1-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: As the others have pointed out, this has to do with the _Pell equation_ $x^2-2y^2=-1$. To make the ratio you observed even more interesting, maybe you should know there is the nice continued fraction, $$\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{2}} =\frac{\sqrt{2}\,e^{-2\pi/8}}{1+\cfrac{e^{-2\pi}}{1+e^{-2\pi}+ \cfrac{e^{-4\pi}}{1+e^{-4\pi}+\cfrac{e^{-6\pi}}{1+e^{-6\pi}+\ddots}}}}$$

Comment: This question has been answered here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2830138/explain-this-convergence-among-pythag-triplets

Comment: each time you to go next line you are adding 5 times more if you divide previous you  will of course approach 5.XXXXx  for example   696 x 5.828427 = 4056.585192 , so you will always stay within the range because each time you are multiplying every result with  5.XXX

Comment: you can see wolfram result you are always within 5.XXX range 696 /119 = 5.848739495798319327731092436974789915966386554621848739495 https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=696+%2F119

Answer (score 7):

> **I. Silver ratio**

What you have discovered is the square  of the *[silver ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_ratio)*,

$$S=1+\sqrt{2} = 2.414213\dots$$

It is a cousin of the *golden ratio*, $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, and share similar properties. Your Pythagorean triple can be expressed as,

$$\Big(\frac{b-1}{2}\Big)^2+\Big(\frac{b+1}{2}\Big)^2=c^2\tag1$$

and factoring ([WA link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5B((b-1)%2F2)%5E2%2B((b%2B1)%2F2)%5E2-c%5E2%5D)), we get the condition,

$$b^2-2c^2=-1$$

This is a *Pell equation*, and given one integer solution we can find an infinite more ([this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html), eqn. 35,36). Since this is the *negative* Pell equation, we use ***odd powers*** $n$,

$$\begin{aligned}
b_n &= \frac{S^n+(-S)^{-n}}{2} = 1,\, 7,\, 41,\, 239,\dots\\
c_n &= \frac{S^n-(-S)^{-n}}{2\sqrt{2}} = 1,\, 5,\, 29,\, 169,\dots
\end{aligned}\tag2$$

The $b_n$ is always odd, so $(1)$ are integers.

> **II. Answer:**

Note that the contribution of $(-S)^{-n} \approx (-0.4142)^n$ in $(2)$ ***rapidly diminishes*** as $n$ becomes large. Thus,

$$c_n\approx \frac{S^n}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

Taking the ratio of $c_n$ for successive odd powers $n$,

$$
\frac{c_{2m+3}}{c_{2m+1}} = \Big( \frac{S^{2m+3}}{2\sqrt{2}} \Big)\Big(\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{S^{2m+1}}\Big)= S^2=(1+\sqrt{2})^2 = 5.828427\dots 
\tag3$$

and we recover your observation.

> **III. Neat stuff**

Just like the golden ratio can be found in the pentagon, the silver ratio $S$ is in the *octagon*,

$\hskip2.8in$[image]

It is also an infinitely nested radical,

$$S = 1+\sqrt{2} = 2\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^2}+\dots}}}$$

and in that nice continued fraction above using $e^{-\pi}$, as well as in a pi formula, etc, etc.

Answer (score 2):

[This explains why the ratios converge to the square of the silver ratio.](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/why-ratios-consecutive-hypotenuses-converge-square-silver-raskin/)

[image: This explains why the ratios converge to the square of the silver ratio. This is primarily what is in the link.]

[image: This demonstrates the convergence of the ratios of the sums of squares of consecutive Pell numbers to the silver ratio.]

[This shows how all of the primitive Pythagorean triples can be generated by 
Pellian sequences, and therefore the ratios of consecutive hypotenuses from any of those sequences would converge to the square of the silver ratio.](http://rationalargumentator.com/issue232/Pellian.pdf)

All of the primitive triples can be listed by sequences with the same recursion relation, just different initial values. The initial values will only affect the coefficients in the explicit forms for those sequences. This will not affect what their ratios converge to as n goes to infinity for each sequence.

THEOREM: All of the primitive Pythagorean triples can be generated, ordered and
largely sorted without redundancy by substitution into {v^2 – u^2, 2uv, v^2 + u^2 } of consecutive pairs of terms of the Pell numbers and similar sequences formed by the same recursion relation, P(n + 2) = 2P(n + 1) + P(n), and initial values n, n + m and n – m, 3n – 2m, where n and m are positive integers, n > m, gcd(m,n) = 1,
and m is odd. 
(The leg difference of triples generated from both sequences is d = 2n^2 – m^2. 
And the Pell numbers can be considered the special case of a singleton sequence: 
n, n + m, . . . , where n = m = 1.)

Comment: interesting references (+1). as per the comment above pls. report the essential lines.

Comment: I don't understand why it's written .  I have given a formula of connection of solutions of this equation with solutions of Pell's equation. Just rewrote my answer in a slightly different form.  That this equation can be reduced to the Pell equation. This has been known for a long time. And it is enough to open the brackets.

Comment: I'm trying to show exactly how to construct the closed form of the Pell numbers, use it to demonstrate exactly why those hypotenuses must converge to the square of the silver ratio and extend all of this to all of the Pythagorean triples.

Comment: Great original question/observation!!! Since the triples represents the rational coordinates of the unit circle ⭕️ and all of the triples can be generated from sequences involving the silver ratio, this connects the silver ratio to the unit circle ⭕️! That may be a big, big deal! And the fact that the sequences lead ratio of hypotenuses to converge means geometrically that we can use all of the triples to approximate the irrational-coordinate point (1/sqrt2, 1/sqrt2) AND the convergence involves the square of the silver ratio!

Answer (score 1):

The values $\; 1,5,29,169,\cdots\;$ are subset of pell number as shown in the OEIS sequence [A000129](https://oeis.org/A000129). You are in fact using the odd-value numbers in the sequence.

If we define Euclid's formula for generating Pythagorean triples as:
$$ \qquad A=m^2-k^2\qquad B=2mk \qquad C=m^2+k^2\qquad$$
the $(m,k)$ values needed to generate these are also Pell numbers and the $n^{th}$ triple can be generated by

\begin{equation}
 m_n= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{n+1} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{n+1}}{2\sqrt{2}}\qquad 
 k_n= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^n - (1 - \sqrt{2})^n}{2\sqrt{2}}
 \end{equation}

If you plug these into $\quad C=m^2+k^2\quad $ and take the ratios between adjacent $C$-value polynomials, it should explain the result you have observed, much as ratios of consecutive Fibonacci number converge to $\phi$.

\begin{align*}
\frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{2} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{2}}{2\sqrt{2}}=2 \qquad& 
     \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^1 - (1 - \sqrt{2})^1}{2\sqrt{2}}=1 \\ 
&\qquad\qquad  F(2,1)=(3,4,5)\\    
 \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{3} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}=5 \qquad &
     \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^2 - (1 - \sqrt{2})^2}{2\sqrt{2}}=2 \\ 
&\qquad\qquad  F(5,2)=(21,20,29)\\
  \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{4} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{4}}{2\sqrt{2}}=12 \qquad & 
      \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^3 - (1 - \sqrt{2})^3}{2\sqrt{2}}=5 \\ 
&\qquad\qquad  F(12,5)=(119,120,169)\\ 
 \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{5} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{5}}{2\sqrt{2}}=29 \qquad &
     \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^4 - (1 - \sqrt{2})^4}{2\sqrt{2}}=12 \\ 
&\qquad\qquad  F(29,12)=(697,696,985)
 \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you should write a general formula, and these issues are constantly emerging.
Solutions of the equation:  $$x^2+(x\pm{a})^2=z^2$$
Can be written using the solutions of Pell's equation: $p^2-2s^2=\pm{a}$

And have the form:

$$x=2s(p+s)$$

$$z=p^2+2ps+2s^2$$

If we introduce a replacement:

$$q=p^2+2ps+2s^2$$

$$t=2ps$$

Solutions have the form:

$$x=t^2-q^2$$

$$z=q^2+t^2$$

Solutions have the form:

$$x=2qt$$

$$z=q^2+t^2$$

It must be remembered that the number of $p,s$ can be of any sign.