# About $n^2+(n+1)^2=z^2$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

**Can it be shown**

(1): $n^2+(n+1)^2= z^2$ has infinity many solution in positive integer $n$ and $z$ ?

Example $(n,z) \in \{(3,5),(20,29),(119,169),(696,985)\}$

(2): $n^2+(n+1)^2+(n+2)^2+...+(n+k)^2= z^2$ has no solution for $k>1$ ?

Comment: http://math.hashcode.ru/questions/71079/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=71097#71097

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1651227/pythagorean-triplets-of-the-form-a2a12-c2-and-the-space-between-them/3282550#3282550

Comment: @individ  thanks, what do you think about second claim.

Comment: The second claim is true for $k=2$. I think the duplicate is helpful, together with individ's links for your title. Tell me if not.

Comment: Yep i got $(n,k,z)= (18,10,77)$

Comment: Using $\mod 4$ can give more details about the possible values of $k.$

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1054544_sum_of_squares

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1054488_the_squares_2    https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1054132_the_squares